# XNA: The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. Normal0 is missing

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

Hey I'm having a little trouble. I've been working with xna for a while, but I'm completely new to 3D. I'm following the code verbatim from the winformsgraphicsdevice sample on the msdn website. It has a control that draws a primitive triangle to the screen. Simple as that, but I get an exception on this line:

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, 1);
```

Which says:

`"The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. Normal0 is missing."`

I'm assuming it has something to do with my `VertexPositionColor` variable, `vertices`. That code is here:

```
vertices = new VertexPositionColor[3];
vertices[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(-1, -1, 0), Color.Black);
vertices[1] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3( 1, -1, 0), Color.Black);
vertices[2] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), Color.Black);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your vertex shader is demanding a *normal* value (used for lighting calculations) but `VertexPositionColor` struct doesn't have it.

You'll have to create a struct for storing vertex position, color AND normal data as it's not a prebuilt type on XNA.

You can learn how to create it here: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_lighting.php

There he creates a struct called `VertexPositionColorNormal`, use it instead of `VertexPositionColor` that you're currently using.

If you don't want any lighting and you're not using `BasicEffect`, just remove your lighting variables/calculations from the technique you're using.
If you are using `BasicEffect` try setting `LightingEnabled` and `TextureEnabled` properties to false.

Comment: You should also set VertexColorEnabled to true, as krolth says. Setting this boolean switches the BasicEffect to not require a normal component.

Answer (score 2):

How are you initializing your shader? If you are using BasicEffect, are you setting the VertexColorEnabled property to true?

The error is saying that the shader/effect that you are using does not match the primitive that you are trying to draw. It is also telling you that the shader is trying to find a Normal (used for lighting) and it cannot find it in the provided structure (since you are providing a color instead).

See this BasicEffect sample to see how you can use it if you want to pass lighting information instead
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203926.aspx